# Owin running before Structure Map configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

On an ASP.NET MVC 5 project using OWIN I have the following:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MvcProj.Site.OwinStartup), "Configure")]

namespace MvcProj.Site {

  public partial class OwinStartup {
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder application) {

      UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

      application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action(MVC.User.SignIn())),
        ReturnUrlParameter = "redirect"
      });

      application.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    } // Configure

  } // OwinStartup

}
```

As you can see I am defining the login path as follows:

```
LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action(MVC.User.SignIn())),
```

I get an error from StructureMap saying I do not have ITranslator defined ...

In fact it is defined but all my controllers are base on a BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller, ITranslator_ {

  public readonly ITranslator _translator;

  protected BaseController() {
    _translator = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ITranslator>();
  } // BaseController

  public String _(String value) {
    return _translator.Translate(value);
  } // _

}
```

So what I think it happens is that Owin runs before my IoC code in global.asax Application Start.

If I remove the code line LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action(MVC.User.SignIn())) then everything works fine.

Could someone, please, tell me how to solve this?

Thank You,

Miguel

Comment: Instead of calling `ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ITranslator>()` in your constructor you should pass an `ITranslator` instance in to it.

Answer (score 3):

The `Microsft.Owin.SystemWeb` host uses the [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [bootstrap itself](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs) which runs before your `Application_Start` method. This is why you're seeing the crash. You'll need to move your DI setup into the `Startup` class.

I've since switched from ASP.NET MVC to [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) but your setup should be similar aside from the need to also setup a dependency resolver for MVC. For this you'll need to install [StructureMap.MVC4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC4/) and then remove the `StructuremapMvc` class it adds since your setup code is now in the `Startup` class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = SetupStructureMap();

        // sets up the mvc dependency resolver
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);

        SetupAuth(app, container);
    }

    private static IContainer SetupStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            // ...
        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }

    public static void SetupAuth(IAppBuilder app, IContainer container)
    {
        app.SetDataProtectionProvider(container.GetInstance<IDataProtectionProvider>());
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = Constants.AppAuthType,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieName = "app.id",
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout"),
            Provider = container.GetInstance<ICookieAuthenticationProvider>(),
            ReturnUrlParameter = string.Empty
        });
    }
}
```

My Startup class is loosely based on the one from [JabbR](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/tree/master/JabbR/App_Start).